# C# Развёртка WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp

Расскажите как правильно развернуть WebAPI. Пробовал на хостинге, но там оказывается нет поддержки asp скриптов, так как он не на windows server, после попытался развернуть его на пк собственном сервере(пк), с прокинутами портами 443, но не получилось... так же если запускать webapi через exe, почему то он запускается со стандартами портами 5000-5001, а когда через компилятор, то уже с моими указанами портами в файле launchSettings.json (443)...
Расскажите как правильно развернуть

Comment: А [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy) почитать?

Comment: Обычно такие штуки упаковывают в докер -образ на этапе сборки проекта и разворачивают на хостинге из докер-образа. Мне кажется, сейчас это самый "модный" способ установки готвого решения на хостинг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под Windows используй хостинг под IIS:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Под Linux можешь под Kestel хостить:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1
Там просто, опубликовал используя RID linux-x64, закинул в linux, создал демона который будет запуска и все - готово! (Не забудь установить dotnet runtime)

Ну а самый лучший путь, это в docker контейнере под каким-нибудь apache, nginx или HAProxy:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1